# C++ constructor with private initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, factory

Not sure if this question has been asked before. I am implementing a factory class. Every instance should inherit from a base class `InstBase` and should be initialized through a centralized factory.

```
class InstBase {
  friend class Factory;      

  private:
    InstBase() = default;
    factory* factory;
}


class Factory {

   template <typename Derived, typename... ArgsT>
   InstBase* get(ArgsT&&... args) {
     return new Derived(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...)                     
   }

}

class MyInst : public InstBase {
   public:
   MyInst(int a, int b) {...};
}

factory.get<MyInst>(1, 2);
```

As you can see in this example, the interface takes a `Derived` as a template and initialize an instance with user-defined argument list passed to the constructor of `Derived`. However, what I want to add here is assigning the pointer to the factory in which the instance is created. This can be done by:

```
   template <typename Derived, typename... ArgsT>
   InstBase* get(ArgsT&&... args) {
     auto ptr = new Derived(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
     ptr->factory = this;
     return ptr;                    
   }
```

I felt this is a bit redundant because the base class `InstBase` is always created before the derived and can be only newed by the factory class. Is there any trick to achieve this goal without changing the interface of `get`? It doesn't make sense for me to ask user to attach another pointer to `factory` in the argument list (e.g., `factory.get<MyInst>(1, 2, &factory)`).

Comment: Your example code : `ptr->factor = this;` looks fine, you dont need `, &factory` in `get` to make it work.

Comment: see here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c05ab3123f168f91

Comment: `Is there any trick to achieve this goal without changing the interface of get?` What exactly is your **goal**? Your suggestion doesn't appear to change the interface of `get`.

Comment: Instead of writing Java in C++ you should just write in Java. Having public inheritance, a private constructor, raw owning pointers and a centralized factory are all terrible things in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forbid the use of `Factory` as a type for the arguments, you can use something like this (C++11 compliant):

```
template<typename>
constexpr bool isBaseOf() { return false; }

template<typename T, typename U, typename... O>
constexpr bool isBaseOf() { return std::is_base_of<T, typename std::decay<U>::type>::value || isBaseOf<T, O...>(); }
```

Thus changing the factory method as it follows:

```
template <typename Derived, typename... ArgsT>
InstBase* get(ArgsT&&... args) {
    static_assert(not isBaseOf<Factory, ArgsT...>(), "!");
    return new Derived(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...)                     
}
```

That said, I don't like it too much, for I won't use a class that does not let me use the parameters I want!!